# amazon ec2 - name server issue

Tags: amazon-ec2, ip, nameservers

i have created new instance in amazon ec2, and assigned the elastic ip for instance. But i need to know how to get ip for name server (ns1.abc.com, ns2,abc.com).

I have installed whm in amazon instance. Only domain cannot point to the correct name server. That is because ip cannot load.

Now, my problem is that how i get new ip. Can i add another two elastic ip in amazon? But i configured two elastic ip for name server in dns zone within whm. The name server is not working. And i cannot open the elastic ip in browser. I am confuse for it. Please anyone help me.

Comment: You can only add 1 IP to an ec2 instance, unless it is hosted within a VPC, then you can have multiple IP's. So you are trying to setup a WHM ec2 instance which runs a DNS server?

Comment: The instance is hosted within a VPC. But i am thinking why eip cannot laod. Why? I want not to use dns server which is provided by amazon. I must register name server by ourselves.

Comment: Server Fault would be more suitable for helping you with issues about your server configuration.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/523283/amazon-ec2-whm-elastic-ip-name-server-issue

Comment: I have confirmed WHM don't support amazon ec2. Although WHM can install in amazon ec2. The issue will occur if more hosting account are created. Each hosting account will point to default page. I DON't RECOMMEND WHM run in amazon ec2. The best answer is migrating to another cloud company (rackspace, softlayer). Their cloud server don't include NAT.

Answer (score 0):

OK, you have two options here:

1. Use the DNS servers provided by your Domain Registrar OR
2. Use [AWS Route53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) to let Amazon provide DNS services for you.

Option 1:

You bought your domain name from a registrar, like one of these: http://lifehacker.com/5683682/five-best-domain-name-registrars

Most, if not all, registrars run a free DNS service for their customers. You should be able to log into some kind of management console and set your domain's DNS zone entries to point at your AWS EIP. (I am using gandi.net and used to use godaddy. You simply leave the DNS Servers as they are and set your AWS EIP as the 'A' record.)

Option 2:

Go to https://console.aws.amazon.com/route53/home and follow instructions. I haven't read up on Route53's pricing, so this option might not be free.

---- EDIT:

Some more help:

The site you've linked to (http://www.intodns.com/xantec.com.sg) states that you've used your EIP (54.251.169.7) as the nameserver for the domain. You don't want that. You're running a cPanel installation, NOT a DNS nameserver.

Put 54.251.169.7 as your site's A record. (Sometimes called the www field.) Remove it from the NS fields and put ns3.thesimpledns.com & ns4.thesimpledns.com into those.

Comment: I selected first option. I have registered one domain in registrar. Two Name server have been added in registrar. The issue is here. EIP cannot load. Why?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things that can go wrong here. I'll try to troubleshoot step by-step:

I'll assume the goal is "You want to type 'whm.foo.com' and see your WHM"

1) Go to your domain registrar and make an entry that points "whm.foo.com" to your EIP. (Depending on what you want, maybe you should setup a "*.foo.com" wildcard for that EIP.

2) Test that step #1 worked by typing "ping whm.foo.com" or "dig whm.foo.com" (one linux/mac, not sure about Windows). This should return your EIP. If not, go back to step 1.

3) Check that WMH is acually running. Read the docs to find what port it's running on. (Usually 2083, or 2082 for insecure access)

On your instance, run "curl -v localhost:2083" (or whatever port. It should return a login screen. If it says "couldn't connect to host", then you have the wrong port or it's not running.

4) run "netstat -na | grep :2083" (or whatever port). It should say "`0.0.0.0:*`". If it says "`127.0.0.1:*`", then you need to configure it to allow outside access.

5) Make sure your WHM port is enabled in the AWS firewall. Go to the AWS control panel and find the security group for your box. Make sure that port is allowed. Ideally, you'd only add your personal IP instead of opening it up to the world. (If there is a bug in WHM, people will scan all IPs trying to exploit it. They can't exploit your server if the AWS firewall denies them access.)

6) Now type "https://whm.foo.com:2083" (or whatever port) in your browser. (or http://whm.foo.com:2082 for insecure access). It should work!

> i need to know how to get ip for name server (ns1.abc.com, ns2,abc.com).

As rdrey said, you need to go to your DNS provider (most registrars also do DNS) and tell them what boxes should point to your EIP.

> That is because ip cannot load.

There is no such thing as "ip cannot load". Either "DNS is giving the wrong IP" or "some IP operations (TCP ports) were blocked by a firewall somewhere".

> Now, my problem is that how i get new ip

I don't think that should be your goal. You can easily change EIPs, but it won't fix the problem. Nothing works unless *everything* in between is set up correctly. The goal should be understanding all the steps in the process and verifying that each step was done correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I have made two name server (ns3.thesimpledns.com, ns4.thesimpledns.com). And pointed their A record to elastic ip (54.251.169.7). Besides, i added hosting account xantec.com.sg in whm. But i cannot open this website xantec.com.sg. Do i know i missing anything? I checked this http://www.intodns.com/xantec.com.sg, the issue seems like name server information cannot be found. Can i know what is that meaning.